# web user control can create a default event?

Tags: user-controls

[DefaultEvent("MyCustomEvent")]

```
public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public delegate void onButtonClick(object sender, Myeventargs e);
    public event onButtonClick btnHandler;

 protected void ASPxButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (btnHandler != null)
        {
            btnHandler(this,e);
        }
    }
```

}

this code can work with 
 public partial class jscript : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        XFButton1.MYClick += new EventHandler(XFButton1_MYClick);
    }

    void XFButton1_MYClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       ASPxLabel1.Text = "Hello";
    }
```

but the problem is i want it automatically generate a new event when i double click on the button. can i done this by using a web user control ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

too bad to tell you that web user control may not able to do like that... pls read this http://dotnet-framework-aspnet.itgroups.info/32/9/thread-796040.html.